# Power BI external user 'Couldn't load the model schema associated with this report'

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, powerbi

I hope one of you guys can help me here, i have a power bi app where external users that are signing in via their personal mails, so they get mail identity. When trying to view the model in the power bi app they get this error:

> The model form associated with this report could not be loaded. Check
> that you are connected to the server and try again. Please try again
> later or contact support. If you contact support, you must provide
> this information.

Users that are in the organization can view it, with no issues.

The external users/setup are as followed:

- The external guest users has been assigned power bi pro license.
- Power bi setting has been set accordingly https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-admin-portal-export-sharing.
- Turned the free license off, so they only have the pro.
- Tried pretty much all the solutions from google page 1-5

Comment: Where is located the dataset? If it is in another workspace the issue can be related to the set up in the dataset workspace.

Comment: @Taisa just seems off as it  is only the "@gmail" users that can not see it. all my Microsoft users can see it??

Comment: Hi @fallenmcmullan, did you get this resolved? Having the same issue!

Comment: @Souf yes i will add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No easy way to do this, had to contact azure support and have multiple of their teams to take a look at it. They ended up admitting that this can not be done

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).